# Formatting Tip Calculator output

Tags: python, function

I am trying to code a function in python that calculates a tip based on two parameters, bill and tip. I'm having an issue because the "tip" parameter has to be in decimal form, like "0.15," but I want it to print out as 15%. This is is my code.

```
def calcTip(bill,tip):
    total = bill + (bill * tip)
    print("A %f%% tip on a bill of %0.2f, comes to %0.2f total." %(tip, bill, total))
```

Comment: Why not just multiply by 100 and then round?

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply tip by 100:

```
print("A %f%% tip on a bill of %0.2f, comes to %0.2f total." %int(tip*100, bill, total))
```